# Htaccess rewriterule doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite the file

```
view-forums.php?page=community-forums&section=2846
```

I have made a rewrite row in my .htaccess file and it's the following:

`RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)/(.*) view-forums.php?page=$1&section=$2` The url should then be http://localhost/forums/community-forums/2846 but it doesn't work when I visit it. It sends me to an error page instead, any ideas?

My full htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)/(.*) view-forums.php?page=$1&section=$2

RewriteRule ^media$ media.php

RewriteRule ^about-us$ about.php

RewriteRule ^forums$ main-forums.php
```

Comment: What "error page" in particular? And `^(.*)/(.*)` will likely match almost everything before all your other rules.

Comment: @deceze It sends me to a 404 error page.

Comment: Also, when i changed the order of the index RewriteRule and the forums one, it broke the css if that's of any help.

Comment: That would be because `^(.*)/(.*)` now matches *everything*, because the `RewriteCond` rules are individual for each `RewriteRule`. Currently your `RewriteCond` rules apply only to the first following `RewriteRule`. If you move your `RewriteRule`s around, the `RewriteCond` will apply to some other rule, and `^(.*)/(.*)` now also matches your CSS files.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, it works, though if i want to add two such as the following `RewriteRule ^forums\/(.*?)\/(.*) view-forums.php?page=$1&view=$2
RewriteRule ^forums\/(.*?)\/(.*) view-forums.php?page=$1&section=$2`  How would that work? Right now, the one that is at the top is the only one that is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the regex lazy, otherwise the first capture group "eats" the second one. Try also escaping `/`.

```
RewriteRule ^forums\/(.*?)\/(.*) view-forums.php?page=$1&section=$2
```

Comment: @Synyster Ok, I'll try to find fix the solution. That said, you shouldn't include the code from the answer into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, though it still won't work, sends me to the error page.

Comment: @Synyster Looks like I've made added `?` to the second by mistake, sorry. Now it must work.

Comment: Hi, i've updated it and it still doesn't work. I'm really frustrated right now. It sends me to 404 error page.

Comment: @Synyster As deceze pointed, try moving this `RewriteRule` above any other `RewriteRule`s.

Comment: Hi again, it works now! Thanks a bunch to both of you two!

Comment: @Synyster Welcome :)